# Выполнение запроса возвращает ошибку "SQL expression is too complex"

Tags: sql, ado

Добрый день. Запрос `select * from STREET WHERE KOD_STR IN(55 параметров)` возвращает ошибку

> SQL expression is too complex

Данные выбираются из таблицы DBF с помощью ADO.

Comment: А привести 55 параметров? Чую что там собака порылась... если 55 параметров это что то типа '1','dfadf','2323',....,'23' то наверное дбф не переваривает такое количество, и надо тогда или эти параметры в таблицу фигачить и сравнивать с таблицей, или разбивать на несколько запросов.

Comment: Там вроде как 2100 параметров ограничение, так что действительно странно.

Comment: Вроде как 24 параметра ограничение, не?

Comment: это срабатывает не ограничение на число переданных параметров, а ограничение на сложность выражения IN

Answer (score 1):

Запишите ваши значения во временную таблицу (или не во временную, если коды — это справочная информация и должна храниться), а затем выполняйте запрос:

```
select * from STREET WHERE KOD_STR IN (select Code from Codes)
```